# How do I forward HTTP traffic from an OpenVPN server to a machine on the same local network as the OpenVPN client?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu desktop (say `orc`) that runs a simple OpenVPN client. The OpenVPN server is called `legolas`.

I want all HTTP traffic coming from `legolas` to be forwarded to a machine, let's call it `gimli`, on the same local network as `orc`. I want `orc` to be the mediator between `gimli` and `legolas`. `gimli` is NOT running an OpenVPN server.

I've trid using FireStarter to configure `orc` as a pseudo-gateway, with the `tun0` device acting as the local interface and `eth0` as the internet device, but to no avail. `legolas` can ping `gimli` but cannot get any HTTP requests through.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You want traffic to be forwarded - how ?

Can these machines talk to each other now ? Are they routed, or NAT-ed ?
Is the OpenVPN setup between orc and legolas a routable tunnel, or peer-to-peer ?

If these 3 machines should be able to comm8unicate directly regardless of the VPN, then proper routing is all you need.

If not - and I suspect this is the case - then you have to NAT something to be carried over the tunnel, and decoded on the other end.